# Pass function with arguments from parent to child in react

Tags: reactjs

[React functional component]
In the parent component, a button onClick will fire a function and this fired function will send another function with some data to the child component.

Actually, I am trying to implement this methodology but can't !!!

How to do it?

Comment: Show what you have tried so we may assist you properly in fixing it.

Comment: Please try to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you've tried and include any details about what is or isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear on what exactly you are trying to achieve but I would start by showing some examples of your code.
Here are the React Docs that may help you
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Check if below code works for you...
--------------------------------------  
  const ChildComponent = ({prop1, prop2}) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Property one: {prop1}</h1>
          <h1>Property two: {prop2}</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }
    const ParentComponent = ({}) => {
      
      const name = "My Name"
      const age = 27
      return (
          <ChildComponent prop1={name} prop2={age}/>
      )
    }
```